# Очень долго выполняется запрос MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Очень долго выполняется запрос. Если я использую только один параметр, то все быстро. Но когда использую OR: `mi.interest_id IN ('$interest_values') OR mt.tag_id IN ('$tag_values')` то долго.

В таблице members_tags около милиона записей.

Поиск должен выдавать всех members по указаным интересам и тагам.

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.email_address 
FROM members m 
LEFT JOIN members_tags mt ON mt.member_id = m.member_id 
LEFT JOIN members_interests mi ON mi.member_id = m.member_id 
WHERE mi.interest_id IN ('$interest_values') OR mt.tag_id IN ('$tag_values')
```

Comment: Один из вариантов, что можно сделать не вникая в проблему. Можно сделать два подзапроса с одним параметром (вы говорите они быстрые) и потом объединить их результаты третьим запросом с distinct

Comment: Если в результате нужны записи, где для конкретного email_address всенепременно есть связанная запись (не null) из members_tags, то может лучше использовать INNER JOIN вместо LEFT...

Comment: Индексы проставлены на IDшниках?

Comment: `union` c `inner join` тогда попробуйте. объемы таблиц хоть опишите, текущие индексы, и время выборки. или план запроса. и что за параметры вы передаете в запрос, сколько там этих значений 1-2 или тысяча? Или может быть даже сделать distinct выборку из member_tags, и уже ее приджойнить к members

Comment: В таблице 1M записей, ты делаешь два JOIN'а (это декартово произведение). Вот и считай, 1M*1M*1M=1T (или 10^18). При условии, что в каждой таблице по 1M, но, учитывая, что ты две других таблицы связываешь с этой, то по логике, в двух других должно быть не меньше, хотя это не точно, конечно =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поскольку таблицы (по крайней мере одна) довольно большие, то не надо их лефт-джойнить друг на дурга, а потом фильтровать. Данный запрос можно эквивалентно разбить на два, используя `union`и `inner join`:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT m.email_address
 FROM members AS m
 INNER JOIN members_tags AS mt ON (
        mt.member_id = m.id 
        AND mt.tag_id IN (....))
 UNION

 SELECT DISTINCT m.email_address
 FROM members AS m
 INNER JOIN members_interests AS mi ON (
        mi.member_id = m.id 
        AND mi.interest_id IN (....))
```

при этом в этих таблицах связи многие ко многим на полях `member_id, tag_id` необходимо добавить индекс.

Возможно также джойнить не сами таблицы связи а distinct-выборку из  них, например

```
 SELECT m.email_address
 FROM members AS m
 INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT member_id 
      FROM members_tags AS mt 
      WHERE mt.tag_id IN (....)

      UNION ... 

   ) as x on x.member_id = m.id
```

и еще потенциально, в таблице `members` можно сделать индекс, включающий  `id` и `email_address`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, теперь все летает! :)

Comment: @akasergej сколько было, сколько стало?

Comment: было около минуты стало секунда :)